# How do I consider the column in the geom_col when there are no elements in it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart

I want to show a bar chart using `Shiny` and `ggplot2` together.

Now, I am using three columns of the data frame in this task.

One is a variable called `Month` with values `c("Month 01", "Month 02", ..., "Month 12")`; the other one is called `income` with numeric values; and the last one, is called `names` with values `c("John", Mathew", "Rodrigo", etc.)`.

The bar height is proportional to the `income` and the categories in the X axis are the months (Month 1, Month 2, ..., Month 12).

The `names` column is just for me to filter and study the bar chart for each particular name.

The problem is that when I compute the bar chart for a certain name, and there are no rows for a given month, then the space where the bar should be is not shown.

Something like this:

[image: As you can see, the space where the column "Month 3" should be is missing]

As you can see, the space where the column "Month 3" should be is missing.

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Rodrigo Guinea

Comment: Tools like `tidyr::complete` can help you turn implicit missing values into explicit ones. Although you can always do it yourself with a simple join with a "key" data frame with a row for each month.

Comment: If `Month` is defined as a factor, then using `scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)` should work.